# django manage.py createsuperuser not accepting username

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and working through [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/) on the djangoproject website. It's gone fine so far but I'm running into issues with the "python manage.py createsuperuser" command.

```
Username (leave blank to use 'alecgo'):
```

When I run the command, the prompt above displays as expected, but when I enter a username, it gets kicked back with the error below.

```
Username (leave blank to use 'alecgo'): admin
Error: Enter a valid username.
Username (leave blank to use 'alecgo'):
```

This happens no matter what I input as a username (or if I leave it blank), and it prevents me from moving forward with the admin user.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update/Edit:** I didn't think to include this but it might be relevant that I have django installed and am running everything inside a virtual environment, not on my main Python library.

Comment: DId you see if that happens for `admin` only, or on any username ?

Comment: I've been googling and found similar issues with solutions regarding ASCII vs. UTF-8 encoding, but I'm not experienced enough to know if that would apply to this problem, or how to check if mine is set right.

Comment: Have you tried leaving it blank and using the default?

Comment: Do you have a link to any of the google solutions? Which OS and shell are you using?

Comment: @DavidSanders Yes, it did the same thing.

Comment: @HåkenLid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210653/django-non-rel-createsuperuser-fails-due-to-non-ascii-characters for example. I'm on windows 7 32-bit and running python out of the standard command prompt.

Comment: Ok. If you are able to do it with the python shell, I think it's better to use that workaround. This could be an error that's caused by a specific combination of database, environemental variables, OS and so on.

Comment: Made some updates to my comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why that would happen, but you can open up the django console using `python manage.py shell` and then do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser(u'username', u'email', u'password')
```

That might work.  You could perhaps also put the above code in a python file (let's call it `myfile.py`) with an explicit encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User.objects.create_superuser(u'username', u'email', u'password')
```

...and then execute the file from the command line like so: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<path to your settings file> python -m myfile`.  You could also just import your file from the django console:

```
from myfile import *
```

Note that, from either the command-line or the django console, you would enter `myfile` and not `myfile.py`.  Also, always ensure that your string literals are prefixed with `u` so python interprets them as code point strings.